# LARAVEL Error: "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I am using laravel version 5.5.45 and trying to learn Blade for first time. I created a file views/layout/app.blade.php. And want to extend that app.blade.php file in views/contact.blade.php. I extended the master blade file using @yield.

Do I need to do any change in route folder?

views/layout/views/layout/app.blade.php

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')

    @yield('footer')

</body>
</html>
```

views/contact.blade.php

---

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Contact Pafg</h1>
@endsection
```

When I hit the URL localhost/cms/public/contact I see the error in title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom route in `web.php` which is located in routes directory.

At the end of file add following code to connect the defined route to your view.

`Route::get('contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});`

Finally you can access it via localhost/contact

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to put the request to get view on browser. Now assuming that your project name: cms lets assume you are calling **cms/contacts** ( this is a get request just to get simple blade view ). Now this will go to ***web.php*** in routes directory, where you need to handle that request e.g.

`Route::get('contact', function() {
     return view('contact');
})`

here assuming your **contact.blade.php** is in your **resources/views/contacts.blade.php** path. if it is within any another nested directory need to add that directory name e.g. **return view('directory_name/contact');**.
You can perform same action using controller method in which case you need to specify controller and method name in route file and return blade in that method. e.g.

```
Route::get('contact', 'controller@methodName');
```

To return blade you need to use **view('blade_name')** helper of laravel and you don't have to call you request like **cms/public/contact**, simply use **cms/contact** url.

Hope this helps.